# 3D objects with unbaked textures does not render properly in metaio sdk

Tags: android, augmented-reality, metaio

I have built an application on top of metaio sdk. I have noticed that the 3d objects that comes with the sdk like metaio man renders properly on the screen. But when I try to use any other 3d objects, the texture for all those objects is white. I am using objects in obj and md2 format as these are the only supported types. 
After researching I found somewhere that we might need to bake the texture using software like Blender. Can anyone please let me know if the baking of textures is a mandatory step for using 3d objects with metaio sdk? If yes, Is there any android plugin that could probably automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you get the model as white texture, it's because your 3d model .obj has to many polygons to get renderized in your device, or that your 3d model is to big to get renderized properly. the solution is to reduce the number of polygons and texture of your 3d model. make it simplest possible. hope to help

Comment: Thanks Sanchez. So does that mean baking of texture is not a necessity? I am just concerned because whatever objects are working for me have one texture file and that is a baked texture. On the other hand, all the non working objects have 2-3 texture files and believe me I have tried a lot of them. Also [metaio documentation](https://dev.metaio.com/content-creation/3d-animation/model-export-from-blender/texture-baking-in-blender/) says that it is necessary to "bake" the texture(s).

Comment: You were right Sanchez. It is the size of the object that actually makes the difference and I am able to render some object without baked textures. Though the metaio documentation says that it is mandatory but actually it is not.

Comment: Good to know, anytime,if you have more questions you can see the metaio helpdesk here http://helpdesk.metaio.com/  now you can vote for the answer

Comment: Sorry but I do not have the appropriate reputation points for that.